# Regrouping Python list items/Organizing given data

Tags: python, list

I'm having problem with regrouping a list in python. The goal is dividing x number of people to approximately 10 group. The list contains requests, some individuals has more request, some of them has none.
One line in the list in which I stored the requests looks like this:

```
r_base=['1' , '2']
```

The first element represents the person who made the request, the second is the requested person.

I figured that it may be a good start, if I could regroup this list(or create a new one) in which everyone who wants to be together is in one line,and none of them are in the list twice.

So the desired list is like:
`requests = [[1,5,8],[2,27,3],[15],...]` if the request was before(for example) : [[1,5],[8,5],[2,27],[27,2][3,2]...]

I am really stucked with this, I tried a couple things, some of them was close, but I didn't find the solution I'm looking for.

```
i = 1
while i < 31:
    requests.append([str(i)])
    i+=1

x = True
for k in r_base:
    x = True
    for s in requests:
        if s[0] == k[0] and k[1] not in s:
            s.append(k[1])
            x = False
        elif x and s[0] == k[1] and k[0] not in s:
            s.append(k[0])
            
a = ''
for x in requests:
    if len(x) > 1:
        a = [x[1],x[0]]
    for s in requests:
        if s == a:
            requests.remove(s)

for s in requests:
    if len(s) == 1:
        requests.remove(s)
```

With this, the output is like:

```
requests =[['1', '14'], ['2', '8', '9'], ['4'], ['7', '22'], ['9', '5', '25', '26'], ['10', '26'], ['12'], ['15', '16'], ['18', '30'], ['20'], ['23'], ['25'], ['26', '8', '9', '10'], ['28', '29']]
```

There are some number that are in the list multiple times, like 9. And I get it, the reason is probably that more than one people asked to be with person number 9, but I don't know how to deal with this. What should I change? Thank you.

Comment: The first list? That is not in the real program, it is just demonstration. In the program I get the lists from files.

Comment: I changed it in the question. Sorry, I'm quite a rookie both here and in programming.

Comment: Can you explain the reasoning (i.e. what your code is *trying* to do) that leads to your desired result?

Comment: (Love the Corgi!)

Comment: So I created the requests list with the 30 people's id in it, which i want to modify later.
And I have the r_base list, thats what includes the requests. I try to process the requests and organize the people in so called miniature groups, so that everyone can be with the desired people. Later I will divide these mini groups to the big ones.
But now, I tried to append the requested ids to the request makers id, and vica versa(so I won't have to groups with the same people in it). And then, I try to delete the list that includes only one person. That happens, but not completly...

Comment: and then there's this other problem I described the end of the question. 
I'm a bit confused, because I think the elimination of the short list should happen based on my code.

Comment: The boolean variable is for to tell whether a request was taken into account or not.

Comment: Sorry for the english, I'm not native. Love your corgi profil pic too :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the meaning of this task correctly:

```
requests = [[1, 5], [8, 5], [2, 27], [27, 2], [3, 2], [15]]

output = []
for group in requests:
    for out in output:
        if any(x in out for x in group):
            out += [k for k in group if k not in out]
            break
    else:
        output.append(group)
print(output)
```

**Output**

```
[[1, 5, 8], [2, 27, 3], [15]]
```

Comment: Yees, thank you, I wanted to do exactly this.